# Как приравнивать значение переменной к одному из элементов списка?

Tags: python, list, переменные

Вопрос заключается в следующем: Как приравнивать текстовую переменную к одному из элементов списка? Код:

```py
denb = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье']
n = input('Введите день недели: ')
for i in denb:
    if n == denb:
       print(i)
```

P.S. Задание: Напишите программу, которая принимает от пользователя день недели в виде строки и выводит его номер на экран.

Comment: вы хотя бы язык в метках укажите.

Comment: исправил, спасибо

Comment: В задании ничего не перепутали? Принять номер дня недели и вывести номер на экран? Но если нужно вывести название, то без цикла можно `print(denb[int(n)-1] if 1 <= n <= 7 else 'Номер не соответствует дню недели')`

Comment: нет, задание написано верно. нужно вывести число, введя название дня недели

Comment: Понял) Читать я разучился)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться методом `index`. Необходимо учесть что счет начинается с нуля.

```py
denb = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье']
n = input('Введите день недели: ')
if n in denb:
    print(denb.index(n)) # с нуля
    print(denb.index(n) + 1) #  с еденицы
else:
    print(f"Дня недели с именем {n} нет")
```

Answer (score 3):

Проверить вхождение можно двумя вариантами через метод списка `index()` или через прямой поиск номера дня через нумерацию списка с помощью `enumerate()` и дальнейшего сравнения строки

```
denb = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье']
n = input('Введите день недели: ').lower()
```

Через `index()`

```
print(denb.index(n) + 1 if n in denb else 'Не тот день')
```

Через `enumerate()`

```
print(next((idn + 1 for idn, d in enumerate(denb) if d == n), 'Не тот день'))
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью enumerate:

```py
dayofWeek = input("Введите день недели: ")
week = ["понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота", "воскресенье"]
print('Номер дня недели:', end =' ')
for number, day in enumerate (week): 
  if dayofWeek == day:
    print(number + 1)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).